# replace text string in entire column after first occurance

Tags: python, string, replace, skip

I'm trying to replace all but the first occurrence of a text string in an entire column.  My specific case is replacing underscores with periods in data that looks like  client_19_Aug_21_22_2022 and I need this to be client_19.Aug.21.22.2022

```
if I use [1], I get this error: string index out of range
but [:1] does all occurrences (it doesn't skip the first one)
[1:] inserts . after every character but doesn't find _ and replace 

df1['Client'] = df1['Client'].str.replace('_'[:1],'.')
```

Comment: It's better not to mark text as code and it's better to provide a `df` example to simplify debugging.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

Not the simplest, but solution:

```
import re
df.str.apply(lambda s: re.sub(r'^(.*?)\.', r'\1_', s.replace('_', '.')))
```

Here in the lambda function we firstly replace all `_` with `.`. Then we replace the first occurrence of `.` back with `_`. And finally, we apply lambda to each value in a column.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `Series` have a [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) method that you can use to apply an arbitrary function to every row in the Series.

In your case you can write your own `replace_underscores_except_first`
function, looking something like:

```py
def replace_underscores_except_first(s):
    newstring = ''
    # Some logic here to handle replacing all but first.
    # You probably want a for loop with some conditional checking
    return newstring
```

and then pass that to `.map` like:

```py
df1['Client'] = df1['Client'].map(replace_underscores_except_first)
```

Answer (score 0):

An example using map, and in the function check if the string contain an underscore. If it does, split on it, and join back all parts except the first with a dot.

```
import pandas as pd

items = [
    "client_19_Aug_21_22_2022",
    "client123"
]


def replace_underscore_with_dot_except_first(s):
    if "_" in s:
        parts = s.split("_")
        return f"{parts[0]}_{'.'.join(parts[1:])}"
    return s


df1 = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=["Client"])

df1['Client'] = df1['Client'].map(replace_underscore_with_dot_except_first)
print(df1)
```

Output

```
                     Client
0  client_19.Aug.21.22.2022
1                 client123
```